# Discrete Logarithm Based algorithm

Tags: encryption, public-key, discrete-logarithm, decryption

The private (secret) key in DL (discrete logarithm) based algorithms is uniformly selected from the group Zq*. This private key is then used to compute the public key. Could the opposite be done, for instance, select the public key uniformly from Zq* and then compute the private key?

Comment: Only if you can solve the discrete logarithm problem. By the way, why did you tag this question with [tag:RSA]?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback just removed the tag

Comment: Obviously if you could select a public key and then compute the private key from it, you would have broken all DLP-based cryptography. The entire point of asymmetric-key cryptography in general is that public key -> private key computation is hard.

Comment: It can be done in the case of [identifier-based cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity-based_cryptography). In this case a central authority has a master secret that enables them to compute the private key for an arbitrary public key.